# Rails - dynamically adding to sortable_element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Am adding to a sortable list using Ajax, and to get the Scriptaculous effects to kick in after the add, the only way I have found is by re-executing sortable_element.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this, at the complete code is a hack:

```
><%= link_to_remote "Add",  
    :url => { :controller => "pages", :action => "add_fragment", :pid => pid, :index => index  },  
    :complete => "eval(decodeURIComponent(#{sortable_element 'frag_list', :url => sort_frag_pages_path, :complete => visual_effect(:highlight, 'frag_list'), :handle => 'handle'}).gsub('//',''));" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer is to add this into the controller method called by the link_to_remote

page.sortable :frag_list